# Show svg logo from advanced custom field

Tags: php, svg, file-get-contents

I want to show a SVG logo which I am taking from the admin panel using Advanced custom field. The logo is then displayed as follow,

```
<?php $logo = get_field('svg_logo'); ?>
<?php echo file_get_contents($logo); ?>
```

Right now this code shows below error,

```
Warning::  file_get_contents(&amp;lt;svg xmlns:dc=&amp;quot;http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/&amp;quot; xmlns:cc=&amp;quot;http://creativecommons.org/ns#&amp;quot; xmlns:rdf=&amp;quot;http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#&amp;quot; xmlns:svg=&amp;quot;http://www.w3.org/2000/svg&amp;quot; xmlns=&amp;quot;http://www.w3.org/2000/svg&amp;quot; xmlns:xlink=&amp;quot;http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink&amp;quot; xmlns:sodipodi=&amp;quot;http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd&amp;quot; xmlns:inkscape=&amp;quot;http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape&amp;quot; height=&amp;quot;206.25000&amp;quot; id=&amp;quot;svg2&amp;quot; version=&amp;quot;1.0&amp;quot; width=&amp;quot;406.25000&amp;quot; x=&amp;quot;0.00000000&amp;quot; y=&amp;quot;0.00000000&amp;quot; sodipodi:version=&amp;quot;0.32&amp;quot; inkscape:version=&amp;quot;0.46&amp;quot; sodipodi:docname=&amp;quot;AJ_Digital_Camera_ok.svg&amp;quot; inkscape:output_extension=&amp;quot;org.inkscape.output.svg.inkscape&amp;quot; inkscape:export-filename=&amp;quot;C:j in.
```

Edit:

I did a var_dump and it shows the following,

```
string(156495) "&lt;svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd' xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape' height="206.25000' id="svg2' version="1.0' width="406.25000' x="0.00000000' y="0.00000000' sodipodi:version="0.32' inkscape:version="0.46' sodipodi:docname="AJ_Digital_Camera_ok.svg' inkscape:output_extension="org.inkscape.output.svg.inkscape' inkscape:export-filename="C:joannaGfxdrawings_vectoradminthumbsAJ_Digital_Camera_ok.png' inkscape:export-xdpi="55.827694' inkscape:export-ydpi="55.827694"&gt;
```

Comment: You should have asked it in wordpress.

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu: I am blocked from asking questions there. Sad.

Comment: looks like the SVG has all the Inkscape metadata in it.

Comment: You need not to use file_get_content if it is .svg. What is result var_dump of `$logo`?

Comment: It is not specific to wordpress either. Post here what `$logo` returns...

Comment: It seems that `$logo` returns some htmlencoded content and failed to decode it.

Comment: @philipp but that should not produce any warning here...

Comment: Does this has to do anything with parsing?

Comment: It seems the svg you're getting it's being urlencoded. Try with the standard fopen, fread, fclose.

Comment: I found the solution. I had missed to select 'convert tags to html' option in acf.

Comment: That is what I was saying that you forgot to `html_decode` thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you select textarea for input, it does not auto select conversion of tags into html. From the advanced custom field options select converting all tags to html.